# Blood consumption

Tags: bacteriology, food, hematology, toxicology, parasitology

Is consumption of blood more *"dangerous"* compared to meat?

There was a news-article about unnatural chemicals found in the blood of mothers. This reminded me about a question I have pondered upon from time to time. Now, I am not a vampire, but curious as to the nature of blood vs meat in animals. More specifically unhealthy components.

There are various examples of viruses being in danger of spreading by consumption of raw blood like ebola, H5N1 etc. (But then also meat etc.)

Perhaps easier if I throw out some questions to show what I am asking:

- Are there more of such in blood then meat?
- Are there other *things* that can be worse in blood even after preparing? Like cooking, conservation etc.
- Are parasites etc. more frequently found in blood?
- Are there organisms that are highly resilient to heat treatment found in blood?
- Are there more heavy metals in blood then meat? (Which I assume cooking does not give much of a difference.)
- Other toxins?

---

Some references:

- http://www.eufic.org/article/en/food-safety-quality/animal-health/expid/review-animal-diseases/
- http://www.fao.org/avianflu/en/qanda.html

Comment: can you reference the news article you have mentioned please.

Comment: @potterbond007: I did not include it as it is not in English. Also, I have thought / wondered about this before, the article simply reminded me about the question. The article itself is a tabloid chock piece: http://www.vg.no/nyheter/innenriks/forskere-du-har-gift-i-blodet-ditt/a/10124215/ The particular subject at hand I have read about before and seen some docus etc. about, but my question is in regards to animal-meat/blood, not human ;), and more in general.

Comment: The (only) answer is actually irrelevant with the question and very ambiguous. What is high dosage of blood...? You can eat a few blood sausages and you will not get iron overload (which is more often an inherited condition). Although everything is digested in the stomach, raw blood could be dangerous if somehow the hypothetical viruses make it to your blood system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is consumption of blood more "dangerous" compared to meat?

Actually yes, a simple high dose of blood is enough to kill. The cause is, though it is most important thing to live when flowing the vessel, it's highly toxic when consumed. There are high chances of getting haemochromatosis or [Iron overload](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_overload).

Source and More on this:

http://www.livescience.com/15899-drinking-blood-safe.html

### Composition of Blood

[image]
<sub>(source: [snmjournals.org](http://tech.snmjournals.org/content/35/2/55/F1.medium.gif))</sub>

Comment: It's the same for menstrual blood?

Comment: My question, at least in my mind, was more in the realm of toxins etc. But as there still are no more answers I'll accept yours as it points out a valid point :)

Comment: I'm highly dubious of the claim, and I'm not sure livescience.com should be accepted as a definitive source. Haemochromatosis is a real thing, but it seems to be associated with multiple blood transfusions and transfusion reactions, rather than consumption of blood as food. [Many cultures include significant amounts of (animal) blood in their cuisine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_as_food), with no obvious problems.